# Adding dropdown to show when checkbox is selected

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox

I currently have a form with checkboxes. I would like to customize checkboxes so that they have a dropdown following them (in the DOM). When the user ticks a checkbox, its dropdown should appear just below it.
Having the dropdown show when the checkbox is ticked is no problem, but I cannot get Symfony to add the dropdown in my form. All I'm able to do so far is having a new field at the bottom of the form, but I need the dropdown to be right after each checkbox.

Also, the dropdowns cannot be generated by javascript since they will contain data from the database. I know I could build a workaround in JS, but I would prefer not using that approach.

I have been searching and trying different things for the past few days but with no success.

Is this possible to accomplish using Symfony2?

Note: I'm looking for the php part of things, the JS to show the dropdown won't be a problem.

Thank you

Comment: You've been searching for what exactly? How to render a select box?

Comment: The PHP part of things? PHP has nothing to do with the DOM. This is entirely a Javascript question. Maybe that's why you haven't found anything on Google.

Either that, or your question just sucks and needs to be re-written an made clearer.

Comment: I added details - it was indeed not so clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are two visible ways to do it.

1-Do all the work in javascript, creating a new combo on the fly when the checkbox has clicked, adding the component to the form with an specific attribute  "name" that allow you to know to what checkbox belong, get the value then and do whatever you need. For example you must have a prepared template for creating the combo like:

```
<select id="onthefly_x" name="onthefly_x">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

And then before create the component replace the "x" for the checkbox vale (If that identify the checkbox as an entity id). In that way you can ask in the controller if exist any onthefly_{id} for each checkbox committed an get it's value.

2- As a second choice you can create the form in a way that the combo always came with the checkbox, but hidden through a class attribute. Then you just need to make it visible on checkbox click. The problem here is that all the combos will be submitted, so you must check in the controller which of them came with a selected checkbox.

Hope you can get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are there absolutely no way of doing this server-side? The JS solution is the one I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Well, I suppose that you can create a form with one combo for each checkbox and make all of them hidden with a class and non required, and then show the component on click .That way could work for you?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what I need. Would you happen to have a good resource on how to accomplish this on hand?

Comment: Sorry, I don't, but there is not hard part in that. Just a tricky form and very few lines of js. You will find a lot of examples of both of them in google. Just be sure to validate what combos came with the checkbox selected, since all of them will came in the submit data. That's all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you put this in an answer so that I can upvote it?

Comment: I'm going to update my answer for put the second choice.

Comment: Done. Although the second choice was the needed by you, I think that the first one is more clean, so I'll leave it in that way.

Comment: Thank you very much